# Sybase binary conversion to Teradata

Tags: binary, byte, teradata

I have a SQL query below

```
select convert(binary(20),convert(char(20),'-'))
```

The output is:
**2D20202020202020202020202020202020202020**

Would like to ask the Teradata equivalent of it. 
below is my query

```
TO_BYTES(CAST ( LPAD('-', 20, '-') AS VARCHAR(20)) , 'ASCII' )
```

But it is resulting me in output:
**2D-2D-2D-2D-2D-2D-2D-2D-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00**

Note: hyphen or - is okay with Teradata, as long as the output is **2D-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result doesn't match your query, but you're using the wrong approach anyway :-)

`LPAD` adds *leading* characters, you need `RPAD` instead, *trailing* characters.

```
TO_BYTES( RPAD('-', 20) , 'ASCII' )
```

Btw, the hyphen is just for making the display of binary data more readable. It's a client setting, e.g in SQL Assistant: **Tools -> Options -> Data Format -> Display dashes between bytes for binary data values**

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot again! :)